# Separating the same material across multiple instances in geometry nodes

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

[image: Here's an image of how it currently looks like]I'm trying to separate a procedural wood material across multiple instances in geometry nodes, the issue is that I need to realize instances to fix a stretching issue I have with scaling the instances randomly which causes the material to see all of the instances as one geometry. Additionally I would like to randomize the location of the material for each instance to avoid repeating patterns due to the instances being in close proximity to each other.

Comment: You could generate a random value for each instance and use vector math to add that to the coordinates of each instance. Thus not appearing continuous. Would need to see images of what youre trying to do to be certain. But I believe that's what youre describing.

Comment: Updated the original post with an image of the project currently, trying to make a wall design with extruding pieces of wood. I'm very new to blender so I will probably need a visual example of what you mean with generating random values for the instances.

Comment: For this specific case you can get away without realizing instances - the material just needs to point to the instancer (the object with the geonodes tree), or just an empty in the world origin, and then divide the Y coordinate by an instances Y dimension - *floor* the resulting number and that's the index of the instance - you can use it to calculate a random offset on the texture (by e.g. multiplying by a big number, and passing to sin function)